# Wp-login.php not getting url parameters

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having an issue with my login function on wordpress. User verification takes place on a separate site, with the only function relevant to wordpress being:

```
header('Location: https://my.site.com/wp-login.php?email='.$email .'&signature='.$mysig);
```

In the wp-login.php, I have set

```
if(isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["signature"])){
    //find user, generate signature, compare with get-signature
}else{
    //error
}
```

Now when I try to log in and for error handling I put in a google redirect in the //error part, that's what happens. Apparently, the 'true' part of the if statement never gets called. I'm wondering if I'm making some obvious mistake with my redirect or wp doesn't allow what I'm trying or something, because for all I can tell this looks correct.

Comment: Are you still on that URL, when the error occurs - or has WP maybe redirected elsewhere already?

Comment: I've tried adding echo statements, but they don't execute, so I used the google redirect. it definitely runs a redirect in the false part of the if statement

Comment: That’s not what I meant, I meant are you still on the URL that includes those GET parameters, when the code you have shown runs. Maybe something else has redirected you elsewhere before already, and then back to the wp-login.php, but this time without the parameters.

Comment: This should probably be handled elsewhere to begin with - _modifying_ WP core script files is not a good idea, your changes will be lost with the next WP update.

Comment: Not sure how I would look at the url there, since the echo "<script>console.log('stuff');</script>"; doesn't work.